# building simplified version of SSL with python

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I need a little help with an assignment.

The goal of my assignment is to build my own simplified version of SSL.
And to use client/server sockets to create a TCP connection.
Part of this is to create the Handshake phase and then Data phase.

Handshake:
1. The client and the server authenticate each other using certificates.

2.The client also informs the server that the data encryption and integrity protection scheme to use
(there is no negotiation). Pick your favorite integrity protection and encryption algorithms and
send it to other side as a string

3.The client and  server also send encrypted nonces(random numbers) to each other. These
nonces are then xored to create a master secret.

So im stuck at number 3 :( have no idea how to code it.

Comment: There is no such thing as *Simplified SSL*. At best it'll be insecure and broken.

Comment: You may take a look at the sources of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl and see if there's any chaff you may separate.

Comment: How are the nonces encrypted?  Does each end of the connection have a public key?  For a slightly different solution, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange